# How to retrieve the value using a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wrote code like this:

```
print re.findall(r'(<td width="[0-9]+[%]?" align="(.+)">|<td align="(.+)"> width="[0-9]+[%]?")([ \n\t\r]*)([0-9,]+\.[0-9]+)([ \n\t\r]*)([&]?[a-zA-Z]+[;]?)([ \n\t\r]*)<span class="(.+)">',r.text,re.MULTILINE)
```

to get this line:

```
<td width="47%" align="left">556.348&nbsp;<span class="uccResCde">
```

I want the value 556.348. How I can get it using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Answer (score 3):

A straight cut and paste from [the HTMLParser documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) will get you the data out of the tags, but not using regular expressions.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# Create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

# Instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<td width="47%" align="left">556.348&nbsp;<span class="uccResCde">')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should explain how to get the matched group. You should read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
import re

text_to_parse= '<td width="47%" align="left">556.348&nbsp;<span class="uccResCde">'
pattern = r'(<td width="[0-9]+[%]?" align="(.+)">|<td align="(.+)"> width="[0-9]+[%]?")([ \n\t\r]*)([0-9,]+\.[0-9]+)([ \n\t\r]*)([&]?[a-zA-Z]+[;]?)([ \n\t\r]*)<span class="(.+)">'
m = re.search(pattern, text_to_parse)
m.group(5)
```

But in order to parse HTML one should not need to use regular expressions. Instead, use an HTML parser, such as [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text_to_parse)
soup.text
```

Comment: The value may keep changing.I want to get the value over there.

Comment: I didnt down vote u. problem is i cant use beautiful soup too. I should use only regular expression